# Bash what is the return value of grep and cut

Tags: bash

when I write something like this:

```
x = `grep "#include  $1 | cut -f2"`
```

or any use with grep, cut like:

```
x = `grep string file.c`
```

I don't understand if `x` is an array or one long string? because when I write

```
echo ${#x[*]}
```

it prints `1`, but I can write:

```
for d in `grep....`
```

as it was an array, please explain.

Comment: Oh I meant with backticks but somehow, It ignores them.

Comment: use $( ... )  instead of backticks. for several reasons, including the one that some programs interpret backticks in an unexpected way

Comment: @Bushmills: right. but programs don't see backticks (unless escaped). bash sees it.

Comment: @user3748682: it's called formatting. check the FAQ.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath, for example, editors where one may want to write a bash script with

Comment: @Bushmills: oh, so I guess I shouldn't use `*` and `-`, as some editors interpret it differently. to make it clear: I have little problem with what you're trying to say, but the actual phrasing is just wrong.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath, the phrasing "including the one that some programs interpret backticks in an unexpected way" - what's wrong with that?  take, for example, joe editor, copy and paste the above command into it, and see what joe makes from it, by "interpreting" the backtick in a way you may not have expected. Can you give me an example of an editor which stumbles over text containing - or *?

Comment: @Bushmills: the editor right here in SO. oh, what can I say.. you shouldn't avoid a regular character used in quite a lot of progamming languages just because the developers of joe decided to map another functionality on that key... just as (I hope) you don't avoid the tab character, even though it works differently in HTML forms.

Comment: "what can I say" - you could say where my phrasing is wrong, as you suggest. you could also say which editor one shouldn't use because of the - and * you claim they have problem with.

Comment: drop the second sentence? it's not really relevant here. if you want to go into details, you can link a related question, I'm pretty sure I saw it once.

Comment: then i wonder why you came up with that if you consider it not relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is giving you a single long string.  This is not called the "return value" of grep or cut, but rather the "standard output" (the text they print which you capture with backticks or perhaps clearer with `$(...)`).

What's happening here is that you get one single string, perhaps even with newlines inside, and then you iterate over it with your `for d in ...`.  In Bash, iterating over a string splits on spaces, so you get one `d` value for each word.  Try this to see it in action, plus a way to avoid it:

```
x="foo bar baz"
for d in $x; do echo $d; done
for d in "$x"; do echo $d; done
```

If you quote in the loop, splitting on spaces will not occur.

Comment: so x contains new line? for example if you have a file a.txt that has 2 lines : 1.include b and in the second 2. include d. and you write x = $(grep #include  $1 | cut -f2) you will have 2 lines : a and b or one line: "a b"?`

Comment: why don't you try it? (it's two lines)

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a string.

In your example `for` loops through *words*.